# Autoload.php no abre y error en include

Tags: php, xampp

estoy haciendo un ejercicio en el que tenemos que usar el phpmailer, hasta el momento no he tenido fallos, pero he instalado el vendor con el composer y todo bien. Pero en el código php que lo tengo así :
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php'; ///error
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
```

En el new PHPMailer() me salta un mensaje diciendo Undefined type 'PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer' en el visual studio lo cual no entiendo tengo las rutas puestas.

Y ya que uso xampp, intento abrir el fichero y me saltan estos otros errores:

> Warning: require(vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such
> file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\EjerciciosClase\index.php on line
> 3
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'vendor/autoload.php'
> (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\EjerciciosClase\index.php on line 3

En el xampp he añadido la ubicación del donde esta el vendor, pero me sigue dando error, he comprobado el PEAR y en el archivo de xampp esta puesto. No se que más probar.

Comment: Es un problemas de rutas, intenta colocando toda la ruta, por ejemplo **_/libsProyecto/PHPMailer/vendor/autoload.php_**

Answer (score 0):

trata usar include  estoy en archivo.php->ingreso a la otra carpeta->carpeta vendedor->archivo.php

```
include '../vendedor/autoload.php'; ejemplo
```

si no funciona ver tu código nuevamente